# wget log only succefull downloaded url

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I want to log only the urls who are downloaded succeffully.
I try with -o log.txt, but that's log everything like headers, ip ...

I just want a simple list like

```
http://example/
http://example/toto.html
http://example/sub/tata.html
```

How I can do this ?

My wget :

```
wget http://example.com/ -r -v -S -R js,css,png,gif,jpg,pdf -o log.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
wget http://example.com/ -r -nv -S -R js,css,png,gif,jpg,pdf 2>&1 | perl -ne 's|^.*URL:(https?://.*?) .*|\1|; print "$1\n"'
```

Notices that I use *-nv* (no-verbose) instead of *-v*.  I also redirected the output from stderr to stdout, so it could be processed in the pipe by Perl.  Broken links have a different format in wget output, so you get only the ones successfully downloaded (which is what you asked for).

Comment: Wonderful !
Just try and its work, just some improvements to do and this is perfect.
Thank you :D